# Calendar in Java is not working for UTC timezone

Tags: java, datetime

My code:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar cal = (Calendar) Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
System.out.println("Gregorian cal time:"+cal.getTime());
System.out.println("utc time: "+simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Both the print statements are showing the same local time.

Comment: And why shouldn't they? you're formatting the same Date (`cal.getTime()`), using the same (default) timezone. So it's normal to get the same result. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: But, I want UTC time. As I mentioned the timezone, it should show UTC time.

Comment: The only difference between your 2 print statements is that one of them gets some string formatting - nothing about the date actually has changed.

Comment: You mentioned the timezone when creating the Calendar object. This allows you to get, for example, the current hour in the UTC timezone when asking the calendar. But you're not doing that. You're transforming the Calendar to a Date (which is just an instant on the universal time line, without any timezone information). And you're formatting this Date in your default timezone.

Comment: Then, what should be the right code.

Comment: The right code to do what? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achive UTC time.

Comment: So, you want to print the current date and time, as it would be displayed on the clock if you lived in the UTC timezone, is that right? If so, create a date (new Date()). Create a SimpleDateFormat. Set the timezone of the SimpleDateFormat to UTC. And format the date using the SimpleDateFormat. Note that Date, Calendar and SimpleDateFormat shouldn't be used anymore if you're usign Java 8. Learn the new java.time classes.

Comment: My apologies for asking such a silly question. I am new to Java.

Comment: No problem. That's what SO is for (although there are probably dozens of questions asking more or less the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the TimeZone of your DateFormatter to "UTC"

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println("utc time: "+simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime utc_time = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println("Date: "+utc_time);
```

works fine

Comment: The Question asks for a value in UTC. So **the use of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) here is incorrect**, as the purpose of that class is to intentionally have *no* offset or time zone. By definition, a `LocalDateTime` cannot be in UTC. A `LocalDateTime` is not even an actual moment, it is *not* a point on the timeline. Your variable name `LocalDateTime utc_time` is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. The legacy classes are an awful mess, poorly designed, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-02-23T03:30:58.431Z

The format of that string generated by `toString` is standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

That's it, you are done.

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to see that same moment as the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) of some particular region, then apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-02-23T09:00:58.431+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

India is five and a half hours ahead of UTC. So when adjusted into `Asia/Kolkata` time zone, note how the time-of-day jumps from `03:30` to `09:00`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), andfz [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).